# ngImgCrop upload preview not showing any pictures in modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently working with ngImgCrop to provide an upload preview (and square crop) of profile pictures.

Unfortunately neither the image preview nor the crop are being displayed.

```js
'use strict';

function UserProfileCtrl($scope, $stateParams, UserService, $modal)    {
    var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
        var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            $scope.$apply(function($scope){
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/panel/views/User/image.html',
                    size: 'lg',
                    controller: UserImageCtrl,
                    resolve:    {
                        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                {
                                    name: 'ngImgCrop',
                                    files: [
                                        '/panel/js/plugins/ngImgCrop/ng-img-crop.js',
                                        '/panel/css/plugins/ngImgCrop/ng-img-crop.css'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]);
                        },
                        image: function()  {
                            return evt.target.result;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#new_image')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
}
```

```js
'use strict';

function UserImageCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, image)    {
    console.log(image);
    $scope.image_start = image;
    $scope.image_cropped = '';

    $scope.submit = function()  {
      
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
}
```

Console.log output is the Base64 img code.

```html
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="cropArea">
                    <img-crop area-type="square" image="image_start" result-image="image_cropped"></img-crop>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Preview image</h4>
                <div class="m-b-md"><img ng-src="{{image_cropped}}" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Chrome Development view:
[DOM View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTmja.jpg)
[Network view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNWoc.jpg)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  If you can trigger an `area-move` event, it will always look at the parent elements and resize accordingly.  So here is what you need to do to trigger that event.

ng-img-crop exposes a service called `cropPubSub` that you can inject into your controller

```
.conroller('someCtrl', function($scope, cropPubSub){...}
```

then, once your modal is open, you can call a trigger event, which should look at the parent elements width and height, and resize you image accordingly.
So for my example i called a function to open the modal

```
$scope.callModal = function(val){
    if(val){
        $('#cropImgModal').modal('show');
        var myEvent = new cropPubSub();
        $timeout(function(){
            myEvent.trigger('area-move');
        },200);  // 200 seconds was about right for me for the modal to be fully open
    }
};
```

Hope this helps somebody